# Django extra_context list_detail no variables present

Tags: python, django, templates, django-queryset

I want to add extra_context to a Userena template so that I can have an extra query in the template:

```
def users_watching(request, username):
    qs = Thing.objects.filter(watchlist__user__username=username)
    return list_detail.object_list(
        request,
        queryset = Thing.objects.all(),
        template_name = 'userena/profile_detail.html',
        template_object_name = 'watch',
        extra_context = {'watch_list':qs},
    )
```

However, nothing is being rendered here:

```
    {% for watch in watch_list %}
         Lorem Ipsum           
         {{ watch.user }}
    {% endfor %}
```

"Lorem Ipsum" is not being rendered, which makes me believe that the `watch_list` is not being included at all. Executing this query in the python interpreter returns values, so I know the query is valid.

---

EDIT:

I think that my method of including this in urls.py may be the problem:

```
url(r'^accounts/(?P<username>(?!signout|signup|signin)[\.\w-]+)/$',
   userena_views.profile_detail,
   users_watching,
   name='userena_profile_detail'),
```

This results in a `TypeError`:

```
Traceback:
File "/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  300.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  207.             kwargs.update(self.default_args)

Exception Type: TypeError at /accounts/SomeDude/
Exception Value: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Are you quite sure that your `users_watching` view is getting `username` as an appropriate value to match against? What does your urls.py for that view look like?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @PeterDeGlopper, I added the url above. Something is wrong when I add `users_watching` to the url definition.. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Each URL pattern should bind to exactly one view. It looks like you're trying to do something like call multiple views to resolve that URL - that's not how they work. One view could call another within its code, but not in the URL mapping.